# Six people (half are female, half are male) for seven chairs.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Problem:
Suppose there are $7$ chairs in a row. There are $6$ people that are going to randomly
sit in the chairs. There are $3$ females and $3$ males. What is the probability that
the first and last chairs have females sitting in them?

Answer:
Let $p$ be the probability we seek. Out of $3$ females, only $2$ can be sitting at the end of the row. I consider the first and last chairs to be at the end of the row.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{ {3 \choose 2 }  3(2) (4)(3)(2) } { 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 3(3)(2) (4)(3)(2) } { 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 3(4)(3)(2) } { 7(5)(4)(3)(2) } = \dfrac{ 3(3)(2) } { 7(5)(3)(2) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 18 } { 35(3)(2) } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 3 } { 35 }
\end{align*}
Am I right?
Here is an updated solution.

Let $p$ be the probability we seek. Out of $3$ females, only $2$ can be sitting at the end of the row. I consider the first and last chairs to be at the end of the row.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{  3(2) (5)(4)(3)(2) } { 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
p &= \dfrac{  (5)(4)(3)(2) } { 7(5)(4)(3)(2) } \\
p &= \dfrac{1}{7}
\end{align*}
Now is my answer right?

Comment: Where did the rest of your numerator $\binom32 3(2)(4)(3)(2)$ come from?

Comment: The $(4)(3)(2)$ comes from the fact that after placing two females at the end, there are $4$ spots available.

Comment: There are 5 spots available, though - just, only 4 are going to be used.

Comment: I get a different value, fwiw. Same denominator.

Comment: Where have you accounted for the position of the other female?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I did not account for the other female in my original solution. Hence it was wrong. My new solution does. I believe it is right.

Comment: Here is a handy way to think about this problem. 3 guys walk in and reserve 4 seats: "Oh no, this seat is reserved for my friend". 3 girls then come in and have no choice but to sit in the 3 remaining seats. So we want the guys to occupy 4 of the 5 seats in the middle, which gives $\frac{5 \choose 4}{7 \choose 4} = \frac{1}{7}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can think of the seating assignment as a random permutation of $7$ items (the three males, the three females, and the empty seat). This random permutation puts a female in the first chair with probability $\frac37$. Conditional on having done that, there are $2$ females left, so one of them ends up in the last chair with probability $\frac26$.

Overall, $p = \frac37 \cdot \frac26 = \frac17$.

There's also the brute force approach: $p = \frac{20}{140}$ by counting.

[image]

With an approach whose denominator is $7!$, the numerator should be $\binom32 \cdot 2 \cdot 5!$: we pick the $2$ females at the ends, pick the order they sit in, and then pick the permutation of the middle. This also gives $\frac{\binom 32 \cdot 2 \cdot 5!}{7!} = \frac{3\cdot 2}{7 \cdot 6} = \frac17$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is that you have the outer seats both occupied with probability $\frac57$ and the conditional probability that they both have a woman is $$\frac{\binom32}{\binom62}=\frac15.$$

So the probability is $\frac57\cdot \frac15=\frac17.$

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would think about it. There are seven of them - three male, three female and an empty chair (say, a ghost). In other words, for any given chair, there are seven equally likely possibilities.

So, $ \displaystyle P = {3 \choose 2} / {7 \choose 2} = \frac 17$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that is closest to your thought process. The three females and the three males are all *indistinguishable*, so we use combinations instead of permutations. Picking any one sex first gives:

$${7 \choose 3} \cdot {4 \choose 3}$$

total possibilities.

Now if two women are already sitting at the ends, then there is one woman and three men left to fill $5$ seats. Choosing the woman first we have:

$$5 \cdot {4 \choose 3}$$

ways and here we can see another simpler approach: where 3 men sit in 4 seats and the women sit in the remaining 3 seats.

Thus the probability is $\frac{5}{7 \choose 3} = \frac{1}{7}$.